# GTK+ same UI theme for all platforms

Tags: c++, c, user-interface, gtk, gtk3

I am starting to write an app which I want to be multiplatform and I am stuck on the part of deciding which UI framework should I use. That's where my question comes from:

Is it possible to have a fixed GTK theme for an application instead of using system active theme? I want my application to look the same across Windows, OS X and Linux instead of trying to look like it's using system native controls.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you don't mind doing some C++/C# interop, MAUI is an option of writing native cross-platform apps with a unified UI and without recurring to using a WebUI.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/what-is-maui?view=net-maui-7.0

Comment: Unfortunately doesn't fit the tags for c++ etc.
For anyone looking, there are quite a few lightweight OpenGL-based GUI libraries out there (usually using IMGUI paradigm) that are pretty good if you like the look they can achieve, e.g. GLFW + Dear ImGui. Initially made for game tools but can be used for full on editors/apps, especially if you need a OpenGL viewport anyway.

Answer (score 0):

"instead of using system active theme? " 
do you mean by: "active"-> "native"

YES, from Gtk+3.0 ,you can use fixed GTK theme by using css themes,it is cross-platform(but it seems QT is even better when crossing platform，in my opinion).

here are some articles about default theme and how to change themes:

https://blogs.gnome.org/mclasen/2014/06/13/a-new-default-theme-for-gtk/

https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-migrating-GtkStyleContext.html

Comment: Thanks for reply! Yes, I am aware, that Qt may be more mature when it comes to cross-platforming (although I remenber Qt having problem with title bars having double the height they should on Windows - perhaps they fixed this already) and may have better documentation, but the main probem I have with it is the licensing, that's why I was debating between GTK, wxWidgets and NuNu, and finally stuck with GTK, just having to confirm it's possible to make it look uniform :)

Comment: Whatever you use GTK, Qt, WX... use always a webview to guarantee a modern UI with the same look.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the same look on all platforms using a real modern UI then your best option is to use Web Technologies.

- GTK - [Cross-platform WebView library](https://github.com/webview/webview)
- Web Browser - [WebUI - Use Any Web Browser As GUI](https://github.com/alifcommunity/webui)

Comment: By 2023, the original issue of my post is pretty much solved by .NET Multi-platform App UI (MAUI).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/what-is-maui?view=net-maui-7.0

Comment: What I don't like about MAUI is that the end-user needs to install a vast .Net core runtime to use your application.

Comment: I don't see it as a problem, because C# is my preferred language anyway and I'd rather use a uniform, fairly complete Framework that does require a few dozen MiBs of space for the runtime than patchworking all the different libs in C and C++ of varying quality and code standards I'd need if having to write in C++.
¯\\_(ツ)_/¯
At this point I just assume the end-user either already has the runtime installed, they don't see it as a problem or if they strongly do not want to install it, then they are just not my target.
But sure, if someone is not a .Net dev, then they might consider a WebUI.